# Coverting SPA template to use razor instead of html view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am interested into looking at SPA's with MVC. I realized I can use Kendo UI controls with this as well, which is great.

So I am following a post at http://a.shinynew.me/post/78038782111/a-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-spa-template which is interesting.

The issue is that I am experienced with mvc and razor, and it looks like this template takes the html route, which seems like a bit of a steeper learning curve, and won't be as easy to leverage my existing code. I can't figure out how to hook up new views to the MVC methods, everything hits the Home / Index method.

Then I read `[link in comments because I need 10 rep to post 2 links]` but the template that you download doesn't seem to have anything under Script/App or App. The project seems completely different now, irritatingly. But then, I noticed this:

> You have two options for SPA views that will be loaded into the SPA:
>   standard HTML (*.html) or ASP.NET MVC Razor (*.cshtml) pages. Because
>   this article is intended for .NET developers—and a lot of enterprises
>   have server-side libraries and frameworks they’d like to continue
>   using in their views—I’ll go with the latter option of creating Razor
>   views.

So my question is, how could I convert the http://a.shinynew.me/post/78038782111/a-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-spa-template template to use Razor views instead of .html

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605877.aspx

Comment: If you are using Kendoui routine then you have to roll your own view loading engine. At present (unless something has changed recently) they only support loading html or id. Also routs in their routing engine are client side and have nothing to do with Server. I have my own kendo routing wrapper to load Server views and can post it once I get to computer.

Comment: Look at the source here http://easyspa.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest looks like using razor...? and the contollers are empty but the CRUD is in the Api folder (confused how they are linked up)

Comment: In spa controllers are usually empty. They are primarily please holders for views. Usually most interactions happen using something ing like web api. Eventually you are trying to place as much client related logic and rendering on the  client while Server is really acting as pipe with validation and other business rules that are not client related. Hope that makes sense.